# Is there a name for this type of data structure?

Tags: oracle, database-design

I'm working with a database that has a structure that few of my colleagues have encountered. The database is a fairly standard Oracle SQL database, but it has a number of tables called xxx_param, which take columns away from the main tables and let you add additional "columns" without altering the data structure in any way.

For example:

Table: Premises

```
Id         | Zip_Code    | Address
0123       | 90210       | 1 Acacia Avenue
```

Table: Premise_Param

```
Premise_ID | Name        | Value
0123       | DoorColor   | Green
0123       | WindowCount | 4
```

So in order to find the door color of a specific premise, you'd write a query like:

```
Select * from Premises
Left join 
(select * from Premise_Param
where Name = "DoorColor") doorColor on doorColor.Premise_ID = Premise.ID
```

So my question is, is there a name for  design of database set up this way?

Comment: key-value-pair table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126271/key-value-pairs-in-relational-database

Comment: This is an "Entity-Attribute-Value" or EAV

Comment: EAV, and it is a disaster of a design.  See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: @EdStevens - having said that, Magento appear to have made a real commercial success of it! I agree though - Joe Celko calls it MUCK - Massively Unified Code Key. I've also heard it called things that I can't write here! :-)

Comment: @Vérace - on commercial success .. sure, just to what the contractor in my linked article did - convince the client that its the greatest thing since sliced bread, charge for your maintenance services, and you have a license to print money!  Your biggest challenge then is to keep the customers in the dark - something which is apparently a lot easier than one would think - and probably the situation in which the OP finds himself.  I like a quote from the linked article when in this situation .. "Run Like Hell"  :-)

Comment: @EdStevens Yes, I have the book and read that story with interest - kind of "train-crash" techie reading. An entire app in one EAV table - "rad dude...". Oracle seem to have picked up on the concept with APEX, though they appear to making a better fist of it - largely by not using EAV or a single table. I'm not saying they're the same by any means, but keeping the app and it's metadata and it's web framework all inside the same database is interesting. I just wish they'd actually write some programmes in it - like a rewrite of their desperate forums fiasco! BTW, I like APEX and toyed with it!